# Extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 in c++

Tags: c++

I'm Getting this error here is my code in class and getting error.

The Array is working fine without class, but when I use class I got the error

```
class books{
    string author[20], title[20], publisher[20];
    float price[20];
    int stock_position[20];
    public: 
    books(){
        author[20] = {"author1", "author2", "author3", "author4", "author5", "author6", "author7", "author8", "author9","author10"};
        title[20] = {"book1", "book2", "book3", "book4", "book5", "book6", "book7", "book8", "book9", "book10"};
        publisher[20] = {"publisher1,", "publisher2", "publisher3", "publisher4", "publisher5", "publisher6", "publisher7", "publisher8", "publisher9", "publisher10",};
        price[20] = {12,23,34,45,56,67,67,78,45};
        stock_position[20] = {7,6,21,23,14,5,12,32,43,06};
    }
    input(string,string);
    find();
    buy();
    edit();
    display();  
};
```

Error:

> ```
> [Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or
> -std=gnu++11 [Warning] extended initializer lists only available with  
> -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types 
>  are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and
>  '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')
> ```

Comment: I would suggest to please try what the compiler suggests and then update your post, should the example not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you initialize a class member, it's assignment.  Member initialization takes place only in a *ctor-initializer-list*, never in the constructor body.

It's also the wrong syntax for what you are trying to achieve, as well as semantically illegal.  There is no "list-assignment" syntax analogous to *list-initialization*.

`author[20]` does not exist, valid indexes are from `0` to `19`.  If it did exist, it would refer to only one `string` not the whole array.

The correct syntax using a *ctor-initializer-list* is as follows (also required C++11 for brace-initialization, there's no list initialization in *ctor-initializer-list* in previous C++ versions)

```
class books
{
    std::string author[20], title[20], publisher[20];
    float price[20];
    int stock_position[20];
public: 
    books() 
        : author{"author1", "author2", "author3", "author4", "author5", "author6", "author7", "author8", "author9","author10"}
        , title{"book1", "book2", "book3", "book4", "book5", "book6", "book7", "book8", "book9", "book10"}
        , publisher{"publisher1,", "publisher2", "publisher3", "publisher4", "publisher5", "publisher6", "publisher7", "publisher8", "publisher9", "publisher10"}
        , price{12,23,34,45,56,67,67,78,45}
        , stock_position{7,6,21,23,14,5,12,32,43,06}
    {
    }
};
```

Prior to C++11, you're out of luck when it comes to specifying initializers for array members, although there is a workaround with `std::array` and a helper function.